# Excel VBA Update Entire Column Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs a SQL query. The query returns a numeric value column.
However, when this column is NULL I want to display "N/A" in the column.

How do I do this using a macro?

Below is my code attempt to date. Thanks.

```
With Sheets("Overview").Range("A:A")
    Set Rng = "A"
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.EntireColumn = "N/A"
    Else
        ' do nothing
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the SQL query puts the text "NULL" into the cells where there was a null value, you can use this:

```
Sheets("Overview").Range("A:A").Replace What:="NULL", Replacement:="N/A", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```